# Is it possible to have a public API gateway open to the world in front of a private EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I was wondering if this is possible. I need to setup up a public API gateway open to the world, connecting to an annoying legacy API running in a docker swarm on an ec2 instance.

I followed the guides on how to set it up here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/, but my API gateway is only available from inside the private EC2 instances. Is it possible to make that API gateway public without exposing the EC2 instance?

I just want to use the API gateway in a way to avoid using the basic auth that this legacy program requires.

I feel like i am missing just one simple part.

Here is the part that makes me thing why its only internally available. all my working APIs attached to lambda functions just say InvokeURL

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLS4x.jpg

[Solved] I had chosen to create my Gateway as private instead of regional when first creating it. Recreating the API gateway as regional again fixed this issue

Comment: This is the guide you are looking for: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-private-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, following will be AWS services you will need to use.

> API Gateway -> VPC Link -> NLB/ALB -> EC2 Instances

follow steps given here -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-private-integration.html